# how to use javascript variable into array in laravel blade file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, laravel

How to use **var aid** value assign into $data array? I am getting error: "Use of undefined constant **aid**". I am working on Laravel 5.4. I want to show  ($data['services'][aid]->servicesubdetails) value in

tage. My code is below:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
        function theFunction(e)
        { 
            var aid= e.target.id;   
            $("p").html('{{ ($data['services'][aid]->servicesubdetails) }}');  
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Your problem is not in javascript. `$data['services'][aid]->servicesubdetails` is not a valid PHP expression unless `aid` is defined as a constant value. Did you mean `['aid`]?

Comment: aid is a javascript variable and having an integer value. I want to pass this aid variable into my array index.

Comment: No, it doesn't work like that. PHP is run server side, javascript will be executed client side by your browser after your PHP script is done.

Comment: @AJAYSAINI did you get your solution ?

Comment: @shajji  it`s solved.     <script language="JavaScript">
 
    function theFunction(e)
    {  
  var data = <?php echo json_encode($data);?>;
  var aid= e.target.id; 
          $("p").html(data.services[aid].servicedetails);   
    }
</script>

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

You can use json to use you PHP array in javascript
Look at [LaravelDisplayData](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#displaying-data) and [PHPJsonEncode](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.json-encode.php)

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    var data = @json($data) 
    function theFunction(e)
    { 
        var aid= e.target.id;   
        $("p").html(data.services[aid].servicesubdetails);  
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Ok but i want to pass javascript variable var aid value into $data array index. Please let me know any solution or another way.

Comment: @AJAYSAINI can you tell us why this solution not valid for you

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes are interrupted by another single quote.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
        function theFunction(e)
        { 
            var aid= e.target.id;   
            $("p").html(“{{ ($data['services'][aid]->servicesubdetails) }}”);  
        }
</script>
```

Notice `“` instead of `‘`.

Comment: thanks but it`s not working. Getting error:  (2/2) ErrorException

Use of undefined constant aid - assumed 'aid' (View: F:\xampp\htdocs\beautybar\resources\views\pages\services.blade.php)